# Algebra over a field generated by a vector space?

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, clifford-algebras

I have just learned about Clifford algebras and am a bit confused by the construction. My understanding is that there is a universal construction, but here is the one I was given for now (Szekeres's A Course in Modern Mathematical Physics):

> Let $V$ be a real vector space with (an in general non-Euclidean) inner product $u\cdot v$, and $e_1,..., e_n$ an orthonormal basis such that the matrix of inner product components in this basis is given by
> $$g_{ij} = \begin{cases} \pm 1 & i=j \\\ 0 & i\neq j \end{cases}.$$
> The Clifford algebra associated with this inner product space, denoted $\mathcal{C}_g$, is defined as the associative algebra generated by $1, e_1, e_2, . . . , e_n$ with the product rules
> $$e_i e_j +e_j e_i =2g_{ij}1, \, 1e_i =e_i1=e_i.$$

In particular, I am confused about this notion of an algebra "generated by" $V$. What does this mean? I am familiar with the definition of an algebra over a field as a vector space (say, $V$) with a product defined thereon, but $\mathcal{C}_g$ seems to be "bigger" than $V$ (as a set) given that it's later shown that $\dim \mathcal{C}_g = 2^n$ (whereas $\dim V = n$). That is, I am familiar with turning $V$ into an algebra over a field, so I'm not sure what's going on here (for example, I assume $1$ here is the multiplicative identity in $V$, but when turning $V$ into an algebra over a field I am in the past only familiar with defining structure constants with respect to a basis, and $1$ is not in our given basis here!).

In the end, I'm wondering what is the definition of algebra generated by a vector space being used? I couldn't find anything on Wikipedia which was intelligible to me.

Comment: What is $g_{ij}$ supposed to mean? If the ei are an orthonormal basis then the inner product $e_i \cdot e_i$ will always be 1. An inner product is by definition positive definite.

Comment: @MatthewTowers We are here admitting non-Euclidean inner products. The third inner product axiom is thus "if $u \cdot x = 0$ for all $x$ then $u = 0$" rather than "$u\cdot u \geq 0$ with $u\cdot u = 0$ only if $u = 0$".

Answer (score 1):

If no other constraints are imposed, then the free (associative) algebra generated by $V$ over $\mathbb{C}$ is the ring usually written $\mathbb{C}[[e_1, e_2, ..., e_n]]$. The elements are "non-commutative polynomials" with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$ (so $e_1 e_2$ is different from $e_2 e_1$), with the operations defined in the obvious way. If we impose additional relations such as $e_i e_j + e_j e_i = 2 g_{ij} 1 $ then we take the quotient $\mathbb{C}[[e_1, e_2, ..., e_n]]$ by the two-sided ideal generated by all the elements $e_i e_j + e_j e_i - 2 g_{ij} 1$.

Informally, we would just say that we introduce multiplication on elements of $V$ with the relations $e_i e_j + e_j e_i = 2 g_{ij}$, under the minimum constraints possible (but still forming an algebra over $\mathbb{C}$, i.e. a ring and a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ which are compatible). Thus a product like $e_1 e_2$ is just some new element (not in $V$), because there is nothing forcing it to be equal to any existing element of $V$. We could call it $e_{12}$. Similarly $e_1 e_2 e_3$ is a new element (which we could call $e_{123}$), and similarly for any product of $e$'s, where the indices are in order, with no duplicates.

But $e_1 e_1$ equals the constant $g_{ii}$, according to the relations given, and a product in the "wrong" order like $e_2 e_1$ can be rewritten as $-e_1 e_2 = -e_{12}$ using the relations.. So the Clifford algebra has dimension $2^n$ because it is generated by all products of $e$'s where the indices are in order and there are no duplicates. These products correspond to subsets of $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ and there are $2^n$ such subsets. Any product of $e$'s can be put into a "standard form", with $e$'s in order, by using the given relations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please see my comment to Daniel below -- I am woefully unequipped at this point to understand what's going on here, but hopefully I will soon.

Comment: I added an informal description and I hope that is helpful. It's actually a fairly simple idea.

Comment: Thank you for supplying that! I suppose what continues to mystify me is what that "something new" in which the "new element" sits in really is. For example, it seems that the unit element $1$ (the multiplicative identity in what I guess is assumed to be a unital algebra?) in $V$ is somehow different/linearly independent of all the $e_i$ since it's part of the basis of the $2^n$-dimensional Clifford algebra, even though the $e_i$ being a basis should mean we can write it as such. As you say, this is something new so perhaps I have no right to expect that this basis fact is true anymore.

Comment: The unit element 1 comes from $\mathbb{C}$, not from $V$. There is no reason for 1 to be expressible in terms of the basis of $V$.

Comment: I am supremely confused then. How then does it make sense to write $e_i e_j +e_j e_i =2g_{ij}1$ (LHS vector, RHS scalar)? Is this a failure of abuse of notation as alluded to by Daniel, in writing $e_i$ etc. as elements of this generated algebra when we actually mean its image in the quotient?

Comment: There is an embedding of $\mathbb{C}$ into $Cl(V)$ (the Clifford algebra of $V$). On the right side, 1 means the image of $1 \in \mathbb{C}$ under this embedding.  Both sides of the relation are in $Cl(V)$.  In this sense, 1 is a vector, but it's a vector in the vector space $Cl(V)$ not $V$.  1 is one of the standard basis elements for $Cl(V)$, corresponding to the "empty product".

Comment: I (sort of) see, but that is a me problem. Thank you for all your patience! I am going to read a little bit more and come back to this question, so apologies for leaving it open for now.

Answer (score 0):

Given a set $X$, you can form the [free algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_algebra) $\mathbf{R}\langle X \rangle$. This algebra satisfies the usual universal property ascribed to "free" algebraic structures. In this case $\mathcal{C}_g$ is constructed by taking $\mathbf{R}\langle e_1,\ldots,e_n \rangle$ and quotienting out the ideal generated by the elements $e_i e_j + e_je_i - 2g_{ij}$ for all $i,j$. If we abuse notation and write $e_i$ to talk about its image in the quotient, then we can say that $\mathcal{C}_g$ is generated by $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ and $e_i e_j + e_j e_i = 2g_{ij}$ for all $i,j$. Informally speaking, $\mathcal{C}_g$ is the "largest" algebra containing the $e_i$ subject to the given relations.

Comment: I am just rereading the Wikipedia page for Clifford algebras now, as well as your link. I'm shocked my textbook would introduce Clifford algebras before discussing free vector spaces etc., which it seems are necessary for the construction? If it's OK, I'd like to read about that first (that's in the next chapter), and then come back to this discussion if it's OK. I think this may take as long as a week or two, so I do apologize. I just don't feel I'm equipped to understand the construction you're describing quite yet.